# Can chmod 777 be a security risk on a personal machine?

Tags: permissions, security

Can 777 permissions increase security risk on an average Ubuntu single-user machine? How? What are other downsides of it?

Thanks

Comment: I really don't know why people have this heavy negative though about this , 777 means grant privilege to every account on the system , assuming you have only one or two account "root and www-data" it's wont be matter , I use 777 to solve issue when editing my files when login as root to the server , I may add another account add assign it to `www-data` group but this will makes me wary more about the new account security .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ofcourse, for example, someone might gain access to a guest account, in that case having chmod 777 all over makes it easier to access private data or modify the system.

Comment: But assuming that no one else has physical access to my computer, can it still cause problems?

Comment: @Dexter Yes.  If its a file that you personally don't have write or execute privileges for (without sudo) then If someone can trick you to run a program or script 777 privileges make it possible for it to do harm.  Linux is largely virus free because it has a strong security model if you have 777 access on files that don't need it you make it less secure/

Comment: yes, because  they will have remote access as well. With that permission they might as well be sitting in your chair.